# how do i open a port and check if it is open

Tags: windows-7, port-forwarding

Sorry being a total NEWB. i have to open port 9312 to make SphinxSearch work with my local xampp server

here is an image of what i have done, i have D LINK router
 http://data.fuskbugg.se/skogsturken/port.JPG
all rows above the highlighted is what someone else have done on this shared network

have i done it right? is it suppose to look like this?  IM USING WINDOWS7 and im a total newb with the command prompt so i dont know how to check if ports are open and what not

i dont know if i should sue 192.168.0.100 or 192.168.0.120, 192.168.0.130.

can someone explain

Comment: I think this question belongs more to superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the IP address of your Windows 7 machine.  From the command prompt run ipconfig to get the IP address of the Local Area Connection.  If this isn't static it should be, otherwise you could reboot and get a new IP and break the port forwarding.

If you need to set a static IP go to the "Control Panel" -> "Network and Sharing Center" -> on the Left hand side click "Change Adapter Settings".  Right click on "Local Area Connection" or whatever your network connection is named and then go to properties.  Now select "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)" and click the  "Properties" button.  Now check the option to "Use the following IP address:".  Fill this in with an appropiate IP address, Netmask and Gateway.  Also don't forget to fill in a DNS server or two.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the port is open with an online tool like this: http://www.subnetonline.com/pages/network-tools/online-port-scanner.php

Comment: it is closed how do i open it